# Number of nodes for each feature -- Python Scikit Learn Decision Tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am using scikit-learn to make a decision tree and I need to know the number of nodes each feature has and the cutoff values on each node. For example, in the tree, I want to know how many nodes the 'size' variable has, or how many nodes the 'location' variable has in the tree, and what are the cutoff values in these nodes if that is possible.

Here is my sample training data:

```
size,count,status,location,is_relevant
0.99,39.19,true,east,false
6.45,58.308,false,south,false
4.844,103.6,false,west,true
4.1,63.209,false,west,false
1.05,52.06,false,west,false
```

Here is my sample testing data:

```
size,count,status,location,is_relevant
2.88,139.78,false,north,true
1.29,11.37,false,south,false
3.6,33.97,false,west,true
1.8,43.93,false,west,false
7.41,60.2,false,south,false
```

Here is the code I use to make the tree:

```
training['location']=pd.Categorical(training.location).codes
testing['location']=pd.Categorical(testing.location).codes

y=training.loc[:,'is_relevant']
x=training.iloc[:, :-1]

from sklearn import tree
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model=model.fit(x, y)
predictions = model.predict(testing.iloc[:, :-1])
print(model.tree_)
print(model.tree_.node_count)
```

I was able to export and visualize the tree, but there are too many nodes to just go and count the number of nodes for the feature I want. Is there a command for this?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Dana, Can you please post the script that you sued to make the decision tree, all relevant outputs, and what the export of the tree looks like? It is impossible to help you in any way if we do not know what you have done so far.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I have edited the original question